# Partition by order of partition columns

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have this window function appled that looks like this:

```
SUM(value) OVER (
    PARTITION BY product, service, site 
    ORDER BY region, site, service, product, year, week ASC 
    ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING
) AS value
```

The Query is working fine but I want to understand more of the window function, I have two questions:

1. Does the partition columns order matters (PARTITION BY product, service, site)?
2. Do I need to specify columns from point 1 in the ORDER BY clause or can I omit them?

Comment: Ans 1 - No.
2 - You need to specify the columns which are necessary to define the order of rows.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the partition columns order matter?

No.

It makes no difference whether you have `PARTITION BY product, service, site` or `PARTITION BY site, service, product` or any other ordering of those three columns.

The members of a partition will be the rows that share the same values for all three of the columns and it doesn't matter how you order them.

> Do I need to specify columns from point 1 in ORDER BY clause or can I
> omit them?

You don't need to specify the columns.

Don't do

```
PARTITION BY product, service, site 
ORDER BY region, site, service, product, year, week
```

Just do

```
PARTITION BY product, service, site 
ORDER BY region, year, week
```

All of the rows within a partition will have the same values for all of `product, service, site` so it doesn't add anything to include these in the ordering.

The query is clearer with these "no-op" elements removed.

Answer (score 1):

- The partition by clause specifies the granularity. In your case it is saying look at all the rows of a given product for a given service at a given site.
- Since it is the granularity the order doesn't matter so you can have the clause

```
PARTITION BY product, service, site)
PARTITION BY service, site, product)
PARTITION BY site, product, service)
```

The Order by clause on the other hand is really important. You have to really think about how you want the function to operate. For example:

if you are using a `row_number()` `dense_rank()` `rank` functions:

row_number() over(partition by user order by sales desc)
would generate a rank starting from 1 based on the granularity. In this case, the rank would start per user for a given sales value, but since it is desc the rank will start from higher to lower and vice versa. A similar thing will happen to all the above-mentioned functions.

`First_value()` operates the same, it fetches the first value of a given column, if you would like to get the user_id with lowest sales. You can get it using `first_value()` with `order by ASC`, but `DESC` would give you the id that has highest sales i.e equivalent to the answer of `LAST_VALUE` as an example, but if you put the order by clause as a desc, it will actually give you the last value

**I would suggest to create a small data set and play with ORDER BY caluse for all the functions that you are interested in**